# Text Files with Python and Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am currently working on an assignment in which I must load strings from a text file, and display certain parts of it in a text box utilizing tkinter.  My teacher has informed us that he wants us to make each line into an individual object.

This is how a text file would look like:

```
*(Item identity #, Quantity,Item, Location, Color)*

**(23871243,20,Remote,California,White)**

**(94938443,10,Socks,Canada,Black)**
```

I would like each these lines to be an individual object, and then call upon a certain attribute, which would then be displayed.  This is what I have so far.
I think the issue may be in the function 'OpenFile', I would like that to return the identity number, which would then be displayed in the text box.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile


class Manager:

def __init__(self, root):
    #The frame for the GUI itself
    mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, relief=SUNKEN, padding="3 10 12 12")
    mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=10, rowspan=10, sticky="NW")

    button_load= ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Load",command=self.OpenFile)
    button_load.grid(row=35, column=17, sticky = "NE", padx=5, pady=10)
    global text_identity
    text_identity = Text(mainframe, width = 15, height = 2)
    text_identity.grid(column=8, row=5, sticky=(N,W))

def OpenFile(self):
    name = askopenfile(mode='r',initialdir="D:/Documents",
                       filetypes =(("Text File", "*.txt"),("All Files","*.*")),
                       title = "Choose a file.")
    return name
    with name as rd:
        global items
        items=rd.readlines()
        items=[x.strip() for x in rd.readlines()]
        lines=[y.strip() for y in items.split(',')]
    return items[0]
    text_identity.insert("1.0",items[0])


    try:
        with open(name,'r') as UseFile:
            print(UseFile.read())
            print(items)
    except:
        print("No file exists")

class Items:
identity=''
num=''
name = ''
location = ''
other = ''

def __init__(self,identity,num,name,location,other):
    self.identity = identity
    self.num = num
    self.name = name
    self.location = location
    self.other = other

def main():
    root = Tk()
    Manager(root)
    root.title("Data Management")
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == main():
    main()
```

Comment: In your `OpenFile` definition, you put something after the `return` keyword and they are never excuted.

Comment: It is now running, thanks!

Comment: One more issue though, how would I assign the attributes listed in the 'Items' class to the ones specified in the text file?